# Make new elements match slide ui settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery slider that is modifying a div css on slide. All is working perfectly, however when I add a new div the settings from the slider are not being attached to the new div until the slider is moved again.

HTML

```
<div class="inputWrap hidden">
  <input class="inputNumber" type="text" value="5">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="boxout">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="add">
  add box
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boxout {

width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.box {

width: 10%;
height: 10%;
background: black;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(".slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    console.log("slide", ui);
    $(".box").css("width", 10 + ui.value * 2 + "%");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find(".inputNumber")
      .val(ui.value);
  },
  create: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).slider(
      "value",
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .find(".inputNumber")
        .val()
    );
  }
});

var slider = $(".slider");
slider
  .slider("option", "slide")
  .call(slider, null, { value: slider.slider("value") });

$(".add").click(function() {
  $(".boxout").append('<div class="box"></div>');
});
```

FIDDLE

In this fiddle you can see how I have everything setup perfectly, but when a new div is added it doesn't match the above box until the slider is used again

http://jsfiddle.net/or5fhsvh/1/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let me know if the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want you need to modify your `click` function on `.add` class.

```
$(".add").click(function() {
 var slideValue = parseInt($('.inputNumber').val());
 var boxWidth = (10+(slideValue*2)) + '%';
 $(".boxout").append('<div class="box" style="width:'+boxWidth+'"></div>');
});
```

It will get the value of the slider, calculate the desired width of the box and then append that box in the UI. This way the width is maintained for all boxes that you are adding with respect to the slider values. And you don't need to slide the slider to reflect that change.

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/or5fhsvh/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Your add function just creates 1 block and doesn't apply the style to it. Whereas all other blocks have their box class' width overridden by inline styles.

You can change your add function to

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    let extraStyle = 'width: ' + $(".box")[0].style.width;
    $(".boxout").append('<div class="box"' + extraStyle + '></div>');
});
```

Comment: This does not work if there is no box exist before user click add box.